# Java Comms PortInUseException when closing and reopening serial connection

Tags: java, serial-port

I've made a program that connects to a device via rs232. I run it with java 1.7 with Java Comms on a laptop running Windows Vista. I'm using a prolific USB-to-serial adapter to connect to this device. It all works perfectly fine until I close the connection and try to reopen it again from the same application. I get the following exception:

> javax.comm.PortInUseException: Port currently owned by Unknown Windows
>   Application

When I close my application entirely and restart it I am able to connect to the port again. I don't have this problem on another (older) laptop, which still has an onboard rs232 port. I've seen a few comparable questions on this website (for example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924516/open-and-close-serial-ports) and [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478873/serial-comm-port-in-windows-remains-owned-after-closing)), however their solutions do not work for me.

My questions:

- Why is my port still owned by my program?
- How should or could I close my port to avoid this exception?
- How does using a USB-to-serial adapter contribute to this problem?
  Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Here is how I open the connection:

```
private void connectToPort(String preferredPort) { 
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
    portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
    if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {

        if (portId.getName().equals(preferredPort)) {
            try {
                serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("PumpController", 2000);
            } catch (PortInUseException e) {
                System.err.println(e);

            }
            try {
                outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
                inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();

                printStream = new PrintStream(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               System.err.println(e); 
            }
            try {
                serialPort.addEventListener((SerialPortEventListener) this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
                serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);


            try {
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(38400,
                        SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                        SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                        SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
          }
       }
    }
    connectedToPort = true;
}
```

This method closes my connection:

```
 public void closeConnection() throws IOException{
        try{
        serialPort.removeEventListener();
        outputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
        serialPort.close();
        connectedToPort = false;
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve conflicts over port ownership, you can register a PortOwnershipListener so that you will be told if another application wants to use the port. Then you can either close the port and the other application will get it, or ignore the request and the other program will get a PortInUseException.

Comment: The problem isn't another application trying to use the port. It's my own application not releasing it properly.